# Programatically is it possible to list up all the path aliases that my site has?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

A site has many path aliases generated using the Pathauto module, or from the user interface.

I want to get all the aliases the site has. how can I achieve this?

Comment: I believe all aliases are kept in the `url_alias` table, so you could query the table.

Comment: In D8 database didn't found such table

Answer (score 2):

I got a fresh installed d8.1 and a fresh pathauto 8.1.x-dev.
I got the url_alias table in my database by installing the module.

the table schema is [pid | source | alias | langcode]

I guess what you want to do is something like this:

```
$query = db_select('url_alias', 'ua')
  ->fields('ua', array('alias'))
  ->execute();
```

that should give you the result you want.

Comment: `url_alias` table is created by `pathauto` module. So, from this table it couldn't be possible to get the path aliases created from user interfaces.

Comment: yes and no.
The url_alias table should exists by default cause the path module is in drupal core now.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 8.0.6 and i don't have this table by default.

Comment: But you can give aliases in the UI.
Maybe you could get a dump of your site and setup https://www.adminer.org/en/ local, which contains a full text search.

Comment: [`url_alias`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/system/system.install?h=8.0.6#n1172)  is added by core and is in 8.0.6.